# How do I create a firewalld whitelist?

Tags: whitelist, firewalld

I've upgraded to CentOS7, with which comes firewalld instead of iptables. How do I configure firewalld to block all except a whitelist of http traffic? I'd like to leave all other services enabled for now.

I attempted to block all incoming with `firewall-cmd --remove-service=http` then `firewall-cmd --reload`  , but that didn't block the traffic.

```
# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (default)
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client http ssh
  ports: 27017/tcp
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

# firewall-cmd --state
running
```

Comment: Please add to your question the active zone, the services active in that zone, list of interfaces as seen by firewalld and the status of the firewalld service.

Comment: You have two separate questions here. Please post only one question per "question".

Comment: I count one. "How do I configure firewalld to block all except a whitelist of http traffic?"